# Regular expression for replace?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I am trying to replace relative url from /abc/bbc.do?count=1 with /bbc.do?count=1 using urlrewritefilter but when I am using the regular expression /abc/(.*)$ and redirect to /1$ it only seems to be capturing bbc.do and not url parameters. Any suggestions?

```
<rule match-type="regex">
    <from>^/abc/(.+)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: the problem seems to be elsewhere -- did you actually check that the string in question has `?count=1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

It looks like the begin anchor is fine, but the backreferences use `%` instead of `$`. Solution is updated.

```
<rule match-type="regex">
    <from>^/abc/(.+)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/%1</to>
</rule>
```

Also, make sure to add `use-query-string="true"` to your `urlrewrite` node. It is false by default.

```
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
```